# How to enter in 2016 Olympics?

Tags: olympics

I am undergrad in economics. I am also a race walker. I want to play in Rio Olympics 2016. But, I don't know when and which procedure is required to get to Olympic stadium. Please help. I will appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Some information on this... [(1)](http://www.ehow.com/how_5665018_enter-summer-olympics.html),[(2)](http://www.sports1234.com/olympics/3598-olympics.html) . But maybe all that really needs to be said, is that if you refer to participating in the Olympics as "play[ing]" -- no offense, but you probably are way out of scope here. The athletes that you see in the Olympics are generally discovered at extremely young ages, and train unimaginably hard for a quadrennial event. Not going to put this as an answer -- I don't really see this as a feasible question.

Comment: Also, your sport is race walking. For how few people participate in race walking, this is really an unattainable goal if you aren't already in an Olympic training program.

Comment: What country are you from?

Comment: Judging from the money lost by the host cities each Olympiad, it doesn't look like economists are allowed at the Olympics.

Comment: See [this answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/3974/1723) for general information about becoming an Olympic athlete.